# Remove outliers per user

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a transactions table where each user has several transactions with some values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS transactions (
  user_id int,
  value float
);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES
(1, 2.0),
(1, 10.0),
(1, 100000.0),
(2, 1000.0),
(2, 2000.0),
(2, 3000.0);
```

How can I filter the outlier transactions of each user? My definition of outlier are the transactions that are 100 times higher than the median of the transactions of that user.

In above data, I should get the following output:

```
user_id,value
1,2
1,10
2,1000
2,2000
2,3000
```

I would only be filtering the third 3 transaction of `user_id = 1` because it is more than 100 times higher than the median for that user.

How can I do that in BigQuery? Is there a solution using `qualify`? I think it should be helpful but I haven't managed to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *
from `project.dataset.transactions`
where true
qualify not value > 100 * percentile_cont(value, 0.5) over (partition by user_id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is an odd definition, but you can use `percentile_cont()` to calculate the median:

```
select t.* except (median)
from (select t.*,
             percentile_cont(value, 0.5) over (partition by user_id) as median
      from t
     ) t
where value > 100 * median;
```

As a note:  outliers are more commonly expressed using standard deviations.

This also assumes that the values are non-negative.  If you can have a negative median, you might have different logic in mind (but your question makes no such distinction).